# C++ organizing utility code, avoiding "multiple definition of .."

Tags: c++, g++

I want to have some global map, which should be used in many places, and few commonly used little functions. Here is how i trying to organize it.

**util.h**:

```
#ifndef UTIL_H
#define UTIL_H

#include <unordered_map>

namespace util {

extern std::unordered_map<std::string, short> rgb2short {
    { "000000", 0 },
    { "800000", 1 },
    { "008000", 2 },
    { "808000", 3 },
    { "000080", 4 },
    /* ... and so on */
};

short some_util_func() {
   /* some util code here */
}

}
#endif
```

**somefile.cpp**:

```
#include "util.h"

/* usage of util::rgb2short and util::some_util_func() */
```

**someotherfile.cpp**:

```
#include "util.h"

/* usage of util::rgb2short and util::some_util_func() */
```

Compiler did not accepted and responded wiith numerous `multiple definition of 'util::rgb2short'`, etc.

So, question is how this util thing should be better organized.

Comment: remove the extern keyword - you are providing a definition in util.h, not externally

Comment: Why are you trying to initialize your map in your header file. And why is your function implementation in your header without being inlined? (which is still likely not a proper solution for what you are trying to do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least when it comes to data, a header should only include a *declaration*. That declaration must contain the `extern` keyword and (the part you did wrong) must *not* contain an initializer.

The sole exception to this (and it's not a common one at all) is if you want a separate copy of the data for each translation unit into which the header is included. In that very specific case, you need to specify that the data is `static` rather than `extern`.

In your case, `util.h` should contain only an extern declaration of `rgb2short`. The definition (including the initializer) should be in some `.cpp` file (e.g., `util.cpp`). Likewise, util.h should not include the definition of `some_util_func()`. It should include only a declaration, and (again) the definition placed in a source file such as a `util.cpp`.

So, util.h would end up looking like this:

```
#ifndef UTIL_H
#define UTIL_H

#include <unordered_map>

namespace util {

extern std::unordered_map<std::string, short> rgb2short;

short some_util_func();

}
#endif
```

Util.cpp would look like this:

```
#include "util.h"

namespace util {

std::unordered_map<std::string, short> rgb2short {
    { "000000", 0 },
    { "800000", 1 },
    { "008000", 2 },
    { "808000", 3 },
    { "000080", 4 },
    /* ... and so on */
};

short some_util_func() {
   /* some util code here */
}

}
```

Then you would `#include "util.h"` just as you've done, but also link `util.obj` (or util.o, or whatever the object file gets named) with the other object files.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the *declaration* in the header and the *definition* in a source file, like so:

**util.h**

```
#ifndef UTIL_H
#define UTIL_H

#include <unordered_map>

namespace util {
    extern std::unordered_map<std::string, short> rgb2short;
}

#endif
```

and in **util.cpp**:

```
#include "util.h"

namespace util {

    std::unordered_map<std::string, short> rgb2short {
        { "000000", 0 },
        { "800000", 1 },
        { "008000", 2 },
        { "808000", 3 },
        { "000080", 4 },
        /* ... and so on */
    };

}
```

This will avoid those errors. For the function, either mark it as `inline` and put the code in the header, or just put the signature in the header (no need for `extern`) and put the body in the CPP file.